# GPS coordinates: 1km square around a point

Tags: javascript, math, gps, coordinates

I was hoping someone out there could provide me with an equation to calculate a 1km square (X from a.aaa to b.bbb, Y from c.ccc to c.ccc) around a given point, say `lat = 53.38292839` and `lon = -6.1843984`? I'll also need 2km, 5km and 10km squares around a point.

I've tried googling around to no avail... It's late at night and was hoping someone might have quick fix handy before I delve into the trigonometry...

I'll be running all this in Javascript, although any language is fine.

Comment: You realize that they won't be "square" in most senses of the word, especially if your points are near the poles?

Comment: Do you need squares, or will radius do the trick?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin Yes, you're right about the "square". For all intents and purposes, the kind of simple square I'm talking about is square enough for me!

Comment: @mna, I need a range to do a search in a database. Hence the square. I don't know how I could search for a circle in a linear database.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12997900/779408

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If the world were a perfect sphere, according to basic trigonometry...

Degrees of latitude have the same linear distance anywhere in the world, because all lines of latitude are the same size. So 1 degree of latitude is equal to 1/360th of the circumference of the Earth, which is 1/360th of 40,075 km.

The length of a lines of longitude depends on the latitude. The line of longitude at latitude l will be cos(l)*40,075 km. One degree of longitude will be 1/360th of that.

So you can work backwards from that. Assuming you want something very close to one square kilometre, you'll want 1 * (360/40075) = 0.008983 degrees of latitude.

At your example latitude of 53.38292839, the line of longitude will be cos(53.38292839)*40075 = [approx] 23903.297 km long. So 1 km is 1 * (360/23903.297) = 0.015060 degrees.

In reality the Earth isn't a perfect sphere, it's fatter at the equator. And the above gives a really good answer for most of the useful area of the world, but is prone to go a little odd near the poles (where rectangles in long/lat stop looking anything like rectangles on the globe). If you were on the equator, for example, the hypothetical line of longitude is 0 km long. So how you'd deal with a need to count degrees on that will depend on why you want the numbers.

Comment: Ok. Jim's 1 mile = 0.014472 degrees of latitude (or equivalently .008983 in km) seems just about right. Many thanks.

Comment: Note: While calculating cos(lat), be sure to convert lat to radians as almost all programming languages use radians in their Cos/Sin trig methods.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something from my notes to be used on Android with its decimal GPS.

Lat Long:
NY City 40N 47  73W 58    40.783333  73.966667

Wash DC 38N 53  77W 02    38.883333 77.033333

yields = 209 miles !! VERY CLOSE

Distance (miles) (x) = 69.1 (lat2-lat1)
Distance(miles)  (y) = 53.0 (long2 - long1)
As crow flys sqrt (x2 + y2) ... duh!@

delta(LAT) / Mile   = .014472
delta(LONG) / Mile  = .018519

Using a box as approximation
To find someone within 100 miles (100 north / 100 south, 100 E / 100 W)
From 0,0
 -14.472 / + 14.472  , -18.519 / 18.519

Comment: ok, so delta_lat is 0.014472 miles and delta_lon is 0.018519? Cool, I'll just convert that to km and I should be sorted. Many thanks for that. I though it was going to be much more complicated than that!

Comment: Distances in latitude and longitude don't obey Pythagoras because you're tracing across a curved surface, not a flat one. Look up the haversine formula to get the correct result — it's not pretty but you can immediately reproduce it in about five lines of code and then shuffle it off into a library somewhere.

Comment: I am aware of this, this works fairly well withing a 200 mile distance which is why I bookmarked it. It's quick on the server.  If you want something more exact .... here ya go! http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp

Comment: REMEMBER if you are going to use squares to make your db queries manageable the diagonal from center on a square can be 50% greater than the radius...hummm what to do?

Comment: Yes, it's a square I'm looking for. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of generating a gps square given the centre would be to use the indirect Vincenty algorithm.The Javascript code here shows how to do it http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. 
Creating a square using a circle isn't to hard. Squares are equal distance to each point. So given a centre point, distance from the centre, change the bearing from 0 or any number depending on rotation of the square and increment by 90 degrees or PI/2 radians. By incrementing by 90 degrees each time and you will up with a square in circular space.

I use this myself for generating GPS points around a centre point with a given distance
.---.
--/-
--0--
-/--
.---.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

`10 km` = `0.08999` radius from a certain `geopoint`. This calculation is only based on latitude values and applies only to geopoints with WGS84 projection.

#### More details

If you want a more accurate answer you must have to calculate it by building a function of some sort. However it still don't guarantee because people even quarrel for the degrees of error. Taking altitude into account, mercator or not, etc.

#### Caution

The value above is just a **rule of a thumb** so don not use it for critical applications.

#### Reference

GIS StackExchange, [*How do I calculate the bounding box for given a distance and latitude/longitude*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/how-do-i-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-given-a-distance-and-latitude-longitude#19761), answer by [David the Australian developer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/5279/david)