# Find near locations with SQLite and Android

Tags: android, sqlite, gps, coordinates

I have a data table in my SQLite database with information about longitude, latitude and description. Given a certain location, I would like to get all the rows with a near distance (10 blocks) from that location.

This is how data is loaded:

```
values.put(LONGITUD_COLUMN,  (int) (-64.14802 * 1E6));
values.put(LATITUD_COLUMN, (int) (-31.36498 * 1E6));
```

So far this is what I have in code:

```
private int cuadras = (int)(-0.02 * 1E6) ; //10 blocks aprox, I guess
private int current_latitude = 0;
private int current_longitude = 0;
```

current_latitude and current_longitude, are loaded with (from LocationListener):

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 current_latitude = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
 current_longitude = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
}
```

And the SQLite query is as follows:

```
String sql = "LATITUD_COLUMN > (" + (current_latitude + cuadras) + ") AND "
+ "LATITUD_COLUMN < (" + (current_latitude - cuadras) +") AND "
+ "LONGITUD_COLUMN > ("+ (current_longitude - cuadras) +") AND "
+ "LONGITUD_COLUMN < ("+ (current_longitude + cuadras) +")";
```

With this result:

```
LATITUD_COLUMN > (-31398170) AND LATITUD_COLUMN < (-31358170) AND LONGITUD_COLUMN > (-64132838) AND LONGITUD_COLUMN < (-64172838)
```

That query returns no results at all, my question is, how can I query the DataBase bringing all the locations near my current location?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you incorporated that condition into an actual sql query of the form: SELECT * from yourtablename WHERE ....; ?   (The dots represent you String sql)

Comment: Hello, yes I did it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12997900/779408

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have your + and - mixed up:

```
String sql = "LATITUD_COLUMN > (" + (current_latitude + cuadras) + ") AND "
+ "LATITUD_COLUMN < (" + (current_latitude - cuadras) +") AND "
+ "LONGITUD_COLUMN > ("+ (current_longitude - cuadras) +") AND "
+ "LONGITUD_COLUMN < ("+ (current_longitude + cuadras) +")";
```

should be

```
String sql = "LATITUD_COLUMN > (" + (current_latitude + cuadras) + ") AND "
+ "LATITUD_COLUMN < (" + (current_latitude - cuadras) +") AND "
+ "LONGITUD_COLUMN > ("+ (current_longitude + cuadras) +") AND "
+ "LONGITUD_COLUMN < ("+ (current_longitude - cuadras) +")";
```

Note the swapped + and - in the last two lines.

`LONGITUD_COLUMN > (-64132838) AND LONGITUD_COLUMN < (-64172838)` is always false. :-)