# Marking points on google maps that are not in Google places

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I searched quite a bit on this in SO, but there was nothing addressing this exact issue. So here it is.

I have a excel sheet of about 100000 geographical points that are not on google places. I need to get the points near my current location - given a binding radius. And show these points in my android app.

I read up on using SQLite database, but before creating a database, I want to know if there is any other way to do this.

Can I just parse this data in KML or some other format or would it be best to use SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

With that many data points I would definitely use a database and then sort them by rough distance from your current map center point, and only add the items to your overlay that meet your threshold (or that should be visible on the map)

See [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695224/android-sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude) here and take a look at the answers, especially the one with the select statement towards the bottom.