# Tracking more than 100 simultaneous geofences with the new Android API

Tags: android, geofencing

I have around 3500 geographical points of interest in an area of 9000 km^2, and I want my app to run in the background and notify the user whenever he or she is in proximity to any of the aforementioned points.

The new [Geofence API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) introduced during Google I/O 2013 seemed perfect for the job, especially as its optimized for battery life, but I can't seem to register more than 100 geofences before I get the status code [GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationStatusCodes.html#GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES) (using a modified version of the demo app).

Is it possible to increase this limit? Perhaps through some setting or API?

Comment: What's keeping you from keeping your points in array and comparing current location to them yourself?

Comment: I could, but then I might have to implement similar battery conservation strategies, like reducing accuracy or update frequency whenever possible. I just thought it would be better overall to make use of an API designed for this purpose, instead of making it myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend downloading all points to a sqlite db on the device. Then find the closest 99 points with something like this: [SQlite Getting nearest locations (with latitude and longitude)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695224/android-sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude) and register those points with Android to monitor.

Then set a "significant change" geofence that you can use to monitor if the user's location has changed enough that when they exit this geofence, you should reload the closest points of interest.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, you're right, this could work. If I take the smallest circle that contains these 99 points, and then decrease its radius until it no longer intersects with any other geofences, it should work as a "significant change" geofence.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a limit of 100 geofences.
I am not sure if this is per application or per application per user.
I have not test this idea, but can you register the first 100 locations closest to your location?

Comment: I ended up writing my own geofence system. 

The locations looked too clustered together for me to only track the closest 100 points, and I probably need the accuracy of the GPS to do this reliably. But then I might as well implement the rest myself.

Still, if you want to use the Geofence API, this is probably the correct solution. So I'll just mark it as accepted.

Comment: @aadnk can you share your own geofence system ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as I wrote it for my employeer. 

But I can explain how I accomplished it: I divded the area into 30x30 cells, with each cell containing a list of geofences that is nearest to the cell's center. To look up a geofence from a point, I linearly search all geofences in the cell nearest to the point, and the three nearest neighbouring cells.

Comment: @rokonoid I did try other more advanced space-partition structures (such as PR-trees), but they had too much overhead on Android and in the case of my data set. Dividing geofences into cells is simple and very fast for static content. Also note that a geofence may be stored in multiple cells, if it happens to be located on a cell boundary.