# Better alternative among location and geofencing api's in terms of resources consumption

Tags: android, android-geofence, memory-consumption

I am making an application which notifies user when he is near certain locations,it may need various geofences to be activated at same time.

since android's [geofencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)'s were recently updated with new [Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) and update mention to improve battery consumption

Is it better to use multiple geofences simultaniously to get notifications or should i send user's location to server on periodic basis and decide there whether to notify user or not

Do multiple geofences consume more memory than retrieving location and sending to server

NOTE:number of geofences may be more than 100 so i can use solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353150/tracking-more-than-100-simultaneous-geofences-with-the-new-android-api) in that case

Answer (score 1):

I've donne something similar but I used BLE, my aproach was to create a RESTful API in the backend where I got all the geofences and tokens and consume it with Retrofit2 so in order to check if the user was near just did a quick operation (cause sometimes you don´t have beacons) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < latitud.length; i++) {
        dest.setLatitude(latitud[i]);
        dest.setLongitude(longitud[i]);
        dist = me.distanceTo(dest);
        if (dist <= 200) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Near of " + lugares[i]+ " get a reward!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I leave the example here, and some other in my git account. Regards and hope it helps.
https://github.com/AlbertoMobileApps/SimpleLocationExample