# how to get nearest location to given latitude-longitude?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I want to develop a location based app.

Requirement: user inserts data(lat-long) and it is stored in SQLite. When user reach at that location he/she will get an alert. I want to define some area(e.g. 1 km) near to this location.
If user is in 1 km circle of this location then he/she get an alert.

I know how to use location listener but do not have idea to fix this area of circle.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695224/android-sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude) but no idea how to use it.

Anybody can suggest me ? Thanks

Comment: This is handled for you by the geofencing APIs in the Play Services SDK: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: Is there any sample how to use it ?

Comment: It's covered in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: I decided to use Geofence Api and looking for good example.

Answer (score 0):

What is so  difficult?

To know whether the current point is inside any of the 1km radius?

A point is inside a circle if the distance to the center is smaller than the radius!

So just use the distanceTo method of CLLocation, and check to be < 1000.
Do that for all points.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numpoints; i++) {
  dist = currentLocation.distanceTo(point[i].latitude, point[i].longitude);
  if (dist < 1000) {
     // found: signal point reached
  }
}
```

Unless you have hundred thsousands of points this approach works,
Load all points to main memeroy into one big array.

Answer (score 0):

```
No need to calculate distance , you can compare the longitude and latitudes within radius of 1km

        double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
        double lon1 = Double.parseDouble(lon);

        double incrlng = 0.85;
        double incrlat = (radius in km)/ (Math.cos(lat1/57.3)*69.1);
         //here below lat1 is your latitude and lon1 is your longitude               
         north = lat1 + incrlat;
         west = lon1 - incrlng;
         south = lat1 - incrlat;
         east  = lon1 + incrlng; 

check your latitude and longitude with the above co-ordinates,like below
if(latitude >= south && latitude  <= north && longitude <= east && longitude >= west)// check the user latitude and longitude satisfies the if condition, if so he is within the 1 KM radius.
```