# python - split query results into multiple objects based on one column

Tags: python, sqlite, object, orm

my program is querying a sqlite database, and thre result is like this (simplified) in the cursor ready to be fetched.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(IMAGE_LOG_DB_PATH)
connection.isolation_level = None
cur = connection.cursor()
sql_query = "Select date, name, count(*) as sells from sellers group by date, name order by date asc;"
cur.execute(sql_query)
result = cur.fetchall()
```

---

```
2023-01-01 | John | 5
2023-01-01 | Mark | 10
2023-01-01 | Alex | 7
2023-01-02 | John | 4
2023-01-02 | Alex | 3
2023-01-03 | John | 3
2023-01-03 | Mark | 4
2023-01-03 | Alex | 3
```

I would need to split this into separate objects for each Name.

```
Object 'John':
2023-01-01 | John | 5
2023-01-02 | John | 4
2023-01-03 | John | 3

Object 'Mark':
2023-01-01 | Mark | 10
2023-01-03 | Mark | 4

Object 'Alex':
2023-01-01 | Alex | 7
2023-01-02 | Alex | 3
2023-01-03 | Alex | 3
```

it would be easy to do with a loop, and if the object exits, add the entry, if not create a new object. but what I have learned so far is that in Python for almost everything there is a handy tool that does things automatically and usually much faster than what my code can do. I have been reading into ORM, but its my understanding (correct me if I am wrong) that ORM replaces also the connection/query to the database and handles everything on its own. And it appears to be slower than the approach i am having right now.

What would be a proper way to do this?

Comment: As an option, make three queries for each name and get three objects at once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558417/how-to-execute-many-select-statements-at-once-using-python-sqlite

Comment: @СергейКох problem is the queries are not three.. they can be any nuber based on the names, that are not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above result of splitting objects upon the name field is definitely possible.

We have a data structure like `dict` in Python, which acts like an associative array. which internally makes sure that keys will be unique. This serves our purpose to save rows on basis of name.

Read more read `dict` here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Your improved code in this scenario will be below:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(IMAGE_LOG_DB_PATH)
connection.isolation_level = None
cur = connection.cursor()
sql_query = "Select date, name, count(*) as sells from sellers group by date, name order by date asc;"
cur.execute(sql_query)
result = cur.fetchall()

assoc_dict = {}

for row in result:
   name = row[1]  # over here we have a field of name
if name in assoc_dict:
   assoc_dict[name].append(row)
else:
   assoc_dict[name] = [row]

#logic goes like if name is already present in our assoc_dict then append more value or else create new list with name as the key

#to access these 3 objects use code below:
john = assoc_dict['John']
mark = assoc_dict['Mark']
alex = assoc_dict['Alex']
... so on
```

Comment: uhm, little extra question: is there a way to have an entry with "mark=0" for the day 2023-01-02?

Comment: Please correct the indents in your answer.

Comment: Sure Sergie.
@sharkyenergy you need to add extra if the condition to a date column. if matched add an item in row, row['mark']=0

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. i guess you need to have the list of all possible names first hand, else you cannot know what rows to add the first day..

Comment: @sharkyenergy please elaborate on what you mean by mark=0. this mark is a entry of name field or a custom field which you want to add in result objects?

Comment: as you see in the result of the query, mark did not sell on january 2nd, thus there is no entry for him. I would need all new objects, to have the same dates, and if there has been no selling that day, then the column 3 should be 0. so that in the end, all 3 objects have the same number of rows, with the same days in it.

Comment: @sharkyenergy got it. sadly in the program "for row in result:" part the line only iterates over the resultset returned by SQL query. You will need more custom code for such result.