# How to get the interval of a geolocation (lat long) ?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am developing an android application, and in my database of dadaos are registered specific points using geo location, as the scope of the application is global, in some time it will become unviable to load so much information of the cell phone, I would only load the geolocation interval, For example, just load the range of the city where the user is, how could this be done? I thought about doing a WHERE with the location range, but I do not think that's possible.

Has anyone ever had a similar situation that could share the solution?

Comment: Yes, I have this implemented in one of my apps. However, you really should try to solve the problem yourself, instead of just posting a general 'Do This For Me' question. Give it a try on your own. If you have any problems post your code and I will help where I can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695224/sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude

Comment: Barns52.Sharing the solution is not sharing the code, my friend, I was wondering if I could share the path of the stones, if what I thought is on the right track. But thanks for saying it's possible.

Comment: Daniel nugent, Many thanks, great stuff