# what's the efficient algorithm to find points in a circle based on geographic coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, search, coordinates

I'm working on an implementation for finding the nearest person based on geographic coordinates. For example, person *A* has coordinates（Longitude and latitude ） *m*, and I want to find the person within the circle of center *m* with radius *x*.

I plan to store the geographic coordinates in a MySQL database, what's the efficient way to search the nearest coordinates?

My specific question is:

1. what fields should be stored in database for efficient search? I plan to store persons' coordinates only.
2. what's the algorithm for finding the nearest person?       I plan to calculate the distance between person A's coordinate and the coordinates stores in the database.

However, I think it is less efficient to calculate if the number of coordinates is huge in the database.

What's the better way to achieve this application?

Comment: How about just extracting everyone that has an X or Y coordinate that could *potentially* be within the radius, and then doing the radius calculation on that?

Comment: If you care about performance, I would definitely consider a column-oriented DB for this kind of problem.

Comment: A "column oriented DB"? If his database wasn't "column oriented" it would probably be one of the NoSQL databases, which would still, to a certain degree, care about "columns" (or document properties).

Comment: Column-oriented vs row-oriented: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS. Both have "columns". One stares the data by column, the other by row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the closest point to a given point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913576/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-given-point)

Answer (score 0):

A simple Pithagoras theorem application:

```sql
-- The coordinates of the person at the center of the "circle"
set @x0 = (select x from persons where id=1),
    @y0 = (select y from persons where id=1);
-- Calculate the distance for each point in the persons table, excluding the "center"
select *, sqrt(pow(x - @x0, 2) + pow(y - @y0, 2)) as distance
from persons
where id != 1
order by sqrt(pow(x - @x0, 2) + pow(y - @y0, 2))
```

Comment: SqRt is not needed (speed increase).  Instead if someone says within 4 miles, you Square that value (16), now SqRt is not needed on every row.

Comment: @ErikPhilips You are right... it can be removed from the `order by` clause

Answer (score 0):

I realize this talks about SQL Server specifically, and not MySql. However, that does not mean you cannot implement a similar solution. (and it seems [MySql has Spatial Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-spatial-indexes.html)).

This is implemented in multiple database technologies using grids.  There a great video that goes in depth about how grid coordinates works on sql bits called [Creating High Performance Spatial Database](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event5/Creating_High_Performance_Spatial_Databases).

Here are a few images of the grid technique from [MSDN Spatial Indexing Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712(v=sql.105).aspx).

Break down the earth into multiple level grids.

[image]

Locate which grids contain some or all of the object (square, circle, whatever)..

[image]

This technique allows inclusion and exclusion very quickly without the need to calculate distance on every object (time consuming crazy like).